# Wordpress automatic head tag

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress automatically creates the head tag  of my website but there are some style instructions that I want to remove. How can I access those lines?

Comment: you mean css ? dont remove just overwrite in your themes stylesheet, or better yet a child theme. If page template specific, place overwrites within `<style>` tags under your get_header() call.

Comment: You'll need to post an example of what your talking about (a link, some source code or a screen shot). We need more details or we can only guess what your problem is. My guess is that you need to edit the head.php file in the directory of the theme you're using.

Comment: Solved using David's solution. Thank you :)